# Something weird using fgets

Tags: c, fgets

If I'm printing the whole string everything looks good, whitespace and indenting looks perfect (I'm loading the source file with this code).

But if I'm trying to print a single character in the buffer I'm getting letters where there are not supposed to be any.

For example, if I print `buffer[2]` I'm getting letters where it should be whitespace, but if I print the whole string the letters aren't there.

Here is my code that's not working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    char *buffer = (char*) malloc(100*sizeof(char));

    FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen("thisSourceFile.c", "r");

    if (!myFile) {

        printf("could not open file");
    }
    else {

        while(fgets(buffer,100,myFile)) {

        printf("%c \n",buffer[2]);

        }
    }

    fclose(myFile);
    free(buffer);
    buffer = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
n
 n
 n

 t

 h


 I
 y

 f

 p

 l


 w

 p

 }



 r
 u


 e
```

As you can se it is printing letters where it should by whitespace. Those letters are not there if I print the whole string.

Comment: How can we help you resolve your non-working code if you show us working code only?

Comment: If the current line in the source file is empty, `buffer[0]` will be a newline: `'\n'`, `buffer[1]` will be a NUL byte: `'\0'` and `buffer[2]` could be anything, most likely whatever was left over from the most recent non-empty line.

Comment: Looks like your editor preserves TABs. So a line that's indented once, like `if (!myfile)` starts with `TAB i f`, and the `f` gets printed.

Comment: Yes dgnuff that sounds like the problem, now I think I understand what is happening. Thank you!

Comment: Are you actually trying to show a file where you think every line starts with 4 spaces?  (You don't say anything about the format of the file in the question, it's not clear why you expect only spaces in output, I'm guessing this based on context). It would be good to update the question to describe the input file (or even post an example that matches the output)

Comment: Try `if (strlen(buffer) >  2) printf("%c \n",buffer[2]); else printf("<short string>\n");`

Comment: The problem is also that fgets reading the indenting as TAB not whitespaces as user3386109 mentioned. So that combined to what dgnuff said gave this strange output.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in parsing a source file and processing each character, this might be a solution.

But there are two constants; `chars`and `num_lines_to_read`.
M.M mentions in the comments below that `isprint()` isn't fully portable and comes with some quirks to be careful of.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    const int chars = 100; /* Num chars per line to read */
    const int num_lines_to_read = 3; /* Num lines to read */
    char *buffer = (char*) malloc(chars*sizeof(char));
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen("thisSourceFile.c", "r");

    if (myFile == NULL) {
      printf("could not open file");
      fclose(myFile);
      return 1;
    }

    for(i=0; i<num_lines_to_read; i++)
    {
      if(fgets(buffer,chars,myFile) != NULL)
      {
        while(isprint((unsigned char) buffer[j]))
        {  
          printf("%c", (buffer[j]));
          j++;
        }
        j=0;
      }
    }

    fclose(myFile);
    free(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Example output (itself!):

```
#include <stdio.h>#include <stdlib.h>#include <ctype.h>
```

Comment: Note - I recall from other questions that some systems and locales vary on whether `isprint('\t')` is true or false. So watch out for this :)

Comment: Also it should be `isprint( (unsigned char) buffer[j] )`. The behaviour of isprint is undefined for negative values other than EOF

Comment: Thanks M.M.  Added that, plus a warning about portability of `isprint()`.

Comment: That happens sometimes